# UIView border line thickens when overlapped with other UIView's Border Line

Tags: ios, uiview

[image: Two UIViews, One behind 'Select Your Country and other behind 'Your Number']
[image: Two UIViews]

Both UIViews have border width 1 and some border color.
When upper view's bottom border is overlapped with bottom view's upper border, you can see the result. Can I make the between line alike the side borders?

P.S Views are laid out without Constraints or Auto-Layouts.

And when adjusting y value of bottom view one down makes the views as:

[image: A space appears]

But I want the line between of the same width as the side borders...

Comment: Just a note: do use auto layout!

Comment: You have to make both view as sub view in any single view and give border to that newly created view and put just single line between that 2 view with same color as border

Comment: @bhoomi: :-) Thanks, yeh to socha e nahi tha..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You and @user3117251 were already pretty close. What you need to do in fact is the following:

**adjust the y-coordinate of the second view that it is equal to

(y-coordinate of the first view + height of the first one - border width).**

You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the views are overlapping? It looks like you actually have the opposite problem. If you are using auto-layout, try constraining the top of the lower view to the bottom of the upper view with a constant value of -1. If you are laying out with frames just adjust the bottom view's y value down one. So long as the borders are totally opaque, one should totally cover the other and it will appear to be one point thick.

Comment: I have updated question by adjusting y value one down, pal. Check that out.

Comment: adjust the y-coordinate in the other direction. In a way that the y-corrdinate of the second view is equal to (y-coordinate of the first one + height of the first one - border width).

Comment: Thanks @luk2302, you are awesome! Take your credit by answering it so that I can mark your answer as right one.